# Pop!_OS 20.04 Realtek PCI problems

Tags: wifi, pop-os

I'm a noob in Linux. My two PCI wifi adapters work fine on Windows. When I install Pop OS! 20.04, go to settings and see "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". How can I solve this?

- AC1200 (Archer T4E)
- TL-WN881ND

Comment: I found a Linux driver (from 2017) for the TL-WIN881ND - https://static.tp-link.com/TL-WN881ND_2.0_LinuxDriverSetup.zip - but nothing for the other one. You may need to boot into Windows and get the chipsets for each adapter, then search for Linux drivers based on that info.

Comment: WN881ND driver is [Linux]2.6.24~4.1. I have linux 5.8, Is this a problem? @ajgringo619

Answer (score 0):

The TP-Link adapter AC1200 (Archer T4E) [is based on](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T4E) Realtek RTL8812AE chipset.
The driver is available from here:
https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au

Comment: The version I need is RTL8812AE, RTL8812AU is the same? Thanks

Comment: The last letter in the device name shows the bus type: U — USB and E — PCIe.
I think rtl8812au would ignore the RTL8812AE.
It was said (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8812au/issues/20) that the modern kernel contains the driver for the RTL8812AE called "rtl8821ae". Try that one.